# AMQ Address with multiple clients to a multicast queue

Tags: amqp, activemq-artemis, jboss-amq

My query is for the product Red Hat AMQ 7.X (and I am using 7.2), which is based on Apache ActiveMQ Artemis and a .Net client connecting to the queue using AMQP protocol.

An Artemis article discusses unicast (point-to-point), multicast (publish-subscribe) and a combination of these addressing: https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/2.0.0/address-model.html

It does not detail the case of two consumers connecting to the same multicast queue under an address. Our requirement is to

- Have pub-sub model of communication, with the publisher publishing to a multicast address.
- Have many queues that can take action based on the published message, say one queue for "FollowupJob" and another for "MailerComponent".
- Have X number of consumers - "MailerComponent" connect to one queue to distribute the load so that the messages delivered to that queue is distributed between the X consumers in a round robin fashion.

A later section describes such a configuration: https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/2.0.0/address-model.html#configuring-a-shared-durable-subscription-queue-with-up-to-10-concurrent-consumers 
It seems to meet my need, but I wanted to double-check as the explanation above did not cover this scenario.

Comment: I recommend you break your 2-part question into 2 actual questions otherwise you may get answers to one part and not the other and it will be difficult to determine which answer is fully correct.

Comment: Thanks @JustinBertram, moved the second part here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51579188/amqpnetlite-activemq-artemis-red-hat-amq-autocreate-multi-consumer-multica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any queue (whether multicast or anycast) can support multiple consumers unless you've set `max-consumers` to `1` or `exclusive` to `true`.